# converting only a region of image to grayscale

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I want to get an image in which only a region has color given a color image.

```
Mat img = imread("lena.jpg");
Rect roi = Rect(100,  100, 300, 300);// only this should be in color in output

Mat img_yuv;
cvtColor(img, img_yuv, CV_RGB2YUV);
vector<Mat> channels(3);
split(img_yuv, channels);
Mat Y = channels[0];
Mat U = channels[1];
Mat V = channels[2];

// create mask
Mat mask = Mat::zeros(Y.size(), Y.type());
rectangle(mask, roi, Scalar(1), CV_FILLED);

// merging channels
channels[0] = Y;
channels[1] = U.mul(mask)+(Scalar::all(1)-mask).mul(Y);
channels[2] = V.mul(mask)+(Scalar::all(1)-mask).mul(Y);

Mat img_yuv_out, img_out;
merge(channels, img_yuv_out);
cvtColor(img_yuv_out, img_out, CV_YUV2RGB);
imshow("masked_color", img_out);
imshow("lena", img);
```

with the above opencv code here are my imput and output images respectively. 
[image: Input]
[image: Output]

In the roi it works fine but rest of image doesn't look like a grayscale image(not exactly as we still have 3 channels.

Comment: When you merge, did you want to assign to 0,1,1 or 0,1,2?

Comment: @RetiredNinja my bad a typo, updating the post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try this:

1. get a copy of the image, and convert it to 3-channel grayscale (I don't know if you need to convert the grayscale explicitly back to (colored) RGB...)
2. get a `Mat` for the ROI you want to have the colors in, once for the grayscale copy and once for the original color image
3. assign/copy the color image ROI to the grayscale image ROI

Indeed, it's exactly as @AndreyKamaev suggests:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

int main() {
    char const * const fname_in = "lena.jpg";
    char const * const fname_out = "lena_out.jpg";
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread(fname_in, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    cv::Mat tmp;
    cv::cvtColor(img, tmp, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    cv::cvtColor(tmp, tmp, CV_GRAY2BGR);
    cv::Rect roi(100,  100, 300, 300);
    img(roi).copyTo(tmp(roi));
    img = tmp;
    cv::imwrite(fname_out, img);
}
```

Output image:

[image: converted lena]

Answer (score 2):

Basically the same as @moooeeeep suggests:

```
Mat tmp;
cvtColor(img, tmp, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
cvtColor(tmp, tmp, COLOR_GRAY2BGR);
img(roi).copyTo(tmp(roi));
img = tmp;
```

Comment: If its "Basically the same", why answer?

Comment: @user2151446 it was the first answer to provide the code snippet. It was perfectly legitimate from my point of view.

Answer (score 1):

To convert roi into grayscale in python you can

1. Convert the roi to gray
2. Replace roi by merging the gray, such that [gray, gray, gray] inplace of BGR
3. Now the roi is gray.

   ```
   image = cv2.imread(image.jpg')
   h, w, _ = image.shape
   r, c, s = h//4, w//4, min(h,w)//2
   gray_portion = cv2.bitwise_not(cv2.cvtColor(image[r:r+s, c:c+s], cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY))
   merged = cv2.merge([gray_portion, gray_portion, gray_portion]) #IMPORTANT 
   image[r:r+s, c:c+s] = merged
   cv2.imshow(image)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to the other way round :-)

```
Mat tmp;
cvtColor(img, tmp, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
cvtColor(tmp, tmp, COLOR_GRAY2BGR);
tmp(roi).copyTo(img(roi));
tmp = img;
```